# Can't make a setup.py file with multiplataform-compiled external modules

Tags: python, cython, cx-freeze

I'm trying to run cx_freeze with a plataform-agnostic setup.py file, i can't figure how to add the compiled files (.pym, .so) into the executable

DataProcessor is a python module compiled externally by Cython ... but i don't know how to include it in cx_freeze executable beacause the absolute path depends upon plataform and python version. So how can i handle that.

<del>the executable is compiled but the external module is not include so when i ran the application throws an error that DLL is not loaded or in case of MacOS says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DataProcessor'`</del>

EDIT: i have seen an error on the original setup.py, correcting this error cx_freeze shows this error

> cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: cannot find file/directory named DataProcessor

EDIT2: as suggested by @mgracer tried to put in in includes section but no sucess cx_freeze shows

> ImportError: No module named 'DataProcessor'

so what i can i do to maintain my setup.py plataform-agnostic.

This is what i have until now

```
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import os.path

# Windows hack
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')
# Windows hack

includes = []
excludes = ['tkinter']
packages = ['openpyxl', 'sqlite3', 're', 'collections', 'os']
include_files = ['DataProcessor']
dll_excludes = []

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {
    "excludes": excludes,
    "includes": includes,
    "packages": packages,
    "include_files": include_files
}

setup(
    name="analizador",
    version="0.1",
    description="Foo bar",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    ext_modules=cythonize("DataProcessor.pyx"),
    executables=[Executable("analisis.py", base=base)]
)
```

Comment: Where have u tried adding .so files and .pym files to

Comment: @mgracer into include_files

Comment: Try the includes section instead i almost always try doing trial and error.

Comment: @mgracer no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved it extending a little the setup.py script
resulted in this:

```
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import os
import platform

# hack para correr en windows
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')
# hack

setup(ext_modules=cythonize("DataProcessor.pyx"))

# rutina detect the files
arch = platform.machine()
temp = platform.python_version_tuple()
pyver = '%s.%s' % (temp[0], temp[1])
pname = None
pext = ".so"
tfiles = ()

if sys.platform == 'darwin':
    temp = platform.mac_ver()
    tver = '.'.join(temp[0].split('.')[:2])
    ptemp = 'macosx'
    pname = '%s-%s-%s' % (ptemp, tver, temp[2])

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    ptemp = 'win'
    pname = '%s-%s' % (ptemp, arch.lower())
    pext = '.pym'

libpath = os.path.join('build', ('lib.%s-%s' % (pname, pyver)))
afiles = os.listdir(libpath)
for file in afiles:
    afile = file.split('.')
    tfiles = tfiles + ((os.path.join(libpath, file), '.'.join([afile[0],
                        afile[2]])),)
# end

includes = []
excludes = ['tkinter', 'PyQt4']
packages = ['openpyxl', 'sqlite3', 're', 'collections', 'os']
dll_excludes = []

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {
    "excludes": excludes,
    "includes": includes,
    "packages": packages,
    "include_files": tfiles
}

setup(
    name="foo",
    version="0.1",
    description="Foobar",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables=[Executable("analisis.py", base=base)]
)
```